# Using FineUploader with optional https?

Tags: javascript, cors, fine-uploader

I have setup FineUploader on a site and I included a check box that allows users to upload files using HTTPS if the want to.

Unfortunately if the user accesses the site using http and then tries to use ssl it errors out, I assume because of CORS issues.  I assume it is a CORS issue because if I access the site using https and try to upload using ssl it works fine.

I found [some documentation](http://blog.fineuploader.com/2013/01/31/cors-support-in-3-3/) about enabling CORS support, but it appears that you either need to make it so only CORS requests will be made or none will be made.  In my situation there will be CORS request some times and not others.

Does anyone know of a good work around for this?  Should I just reload the entire page using HTTPS when the checkbox is clicked?

Comment: Is your problem solved if you reload the entire page using HTTPS?  Also, is there some way you could instantiate Fine Uploader after the user decides if they want to use HTTPS or not?  Just trying to get a bit more information about your situation.

Comment: Yes, if I hit the page using HTTPS and then upload using HTTPS it works.  If I hit using HTTPS and try to upload using HTTP it errors.  You could take the above two sentences and swap HTTP/HTTPS and it would still be true.  I'm sure I could instantiate when the user selects but I believe there would still be a CORS issue.

Comment: If you instantiate after the user selects, if CORS is required, you would simply enable the CORS feature and everything should work.  Are you running into some other issue?

Comment: Ahh, I see what you are saying.  That could work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to reiterate what I've mentioned in my comments (so others can easily see this)...

Perhaps you can instantiate Fine Uploader after the user selects HTTP or HTTPS as a protocol for uploads.  If you must, you can enabled the CORS feature via the `expected` property of the `cors` option.  Keep in mind that there are some details server-side you must address when handling CORS requests, especially if IE9 or older is involved.  Please see [my blog post on the CORS feature](http://blog.fineuploader.com/2013/01/31/cors-support-in-3-3/) for more details.

Comment: So I tried to setup a simple version that did a CORS request by default, but it is still erroring out. I just set `expected: true` for `cors` and on the server side I added the response header: `Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*` which I thought would be ok since I wasn't using `sendCredentials: true`.  Does that make sense?  If so, any idea why it would still be erroring out?

Comment: Are you accounting for the initial OPTIONS request as well?  This is required when handling preflighted CORS requests.  All CORS XHR requests sent by Fine Uploader must be preflighted by the user agent.  You can read more about this in [my blog post on CORS support in Fine Uploader](http://blog.fineuploader.com/2013/01/cors-support-in-33.html).

Comment: I don't think I am.  How would I go about handling OPTIONS on the server side?  Is this what you were referring to when you say: `Your responses must include the appropriate Access-Control headers.`  If so, could you go into some more detail on what exactly I need to do?

Comment: I highly suggest reading the blog post I linked to first to get a better understanding of not only how CORS requests are handled by browsers in general, but also how Fine Uploader CORS support works (for XHR and non-XHR requests).  That said, I'm not sure what server-side language you are using.  Have a look at the Java example in [the server-side examples repo](https://github.com/Widen/fine-uploader-server) to see how I handle OPTIONS requests in Java.

Comment: Ray, I went through the article you pointed me to as well as the Java code sample.  I believe I have my server side setup correctly but I am still unable to upload http->https.  When I look at the actual XHR request it is not even getting a response from the server and if I check the logs on my server there is no indication that the request ever got there.  I know it's a long shot, but do you have any suggestions on where to look to debug this?  I'm running out of ideas.

Comment: @AbeMiessler Send me an email at so-15815996@fineuploader.com and we can discuss further.  I'll need you to provide a link to your app so I can take a peek.

Comment: Ok, thank you so much.  I'll get everything deployed to a url you can hit and drop you an email.

Answer (score 4):

**If you're uploading straight to Amazon s3**, see the note in the [official docs](http:////%20Alternative%20might%20be%20just%20the%20double%20slash%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20//%20default%20documentation%20suggests%20the%20simpler%20mybucket.s3.amazonaws.com), *"SSL is also supported, in which case your `endpoint` address must start with `https://`"* in the script within your uploaderpage.html file.

```
request: {
    endpoint: 'https://mybucket.s3.amazonaws.com', 
                // Note that "https://" added before bucket name, to work over https                     
    accessKey: 'AKIAblablabla' // as per the specific IAM account
},
```

- This will still work if uploaderpage.html is served over http (or you could populate the endpoint value dynamically if you need flexibility re endpoint).
- This will help you avoid the mixed content error when uploading over https, "requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint", which happens if the page is https but you request a http endpoint.

Comment: This solution works, it means I can work on localhost and on production with https .... thanks :)